# Show and hide with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    <body>
    <input type="textbox" id="fname"></input>
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:show('select'); return false;">Click</button></br>
    <input type="radio" id="select" style="display:none;"></input>
</body>
```

The code that i have written seems to be logical but in this case when i click the button it doesnt seem to be working .. Any any one tell me where could i have gone wrong

thanks in advance.

```
    <head>
    <title>show and hide javascript</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function show(id) {
            //alert("Its working");
            var myId = document.getElementById.id;
            if (myId.style.display = 'none') {
                myId.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                myId.style.display = 'none';
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: your `if(myId.style.display='none'` should be `=='none'`

Comment: First time I've ever seen `<input></input>`

Comment: i made it ='none' to =='none' but still its not working.

Comment: Remove the dot after getElementById

Comment: see my post and sample code works fine

Answer (score 1):

I see three issues with your function:

**1)** Correct the `=` to a `==` in this line:

```
if (myId.style.display == 'none') {
```

**2)** Change this:

```
document.getElementById.id;
```

to this to make it an actual function call:

```
document.getElementById(id);
```

**3)** Use a cross browser `getStyle()` function so that your style values will include CSS settings, not just what is set directly on the object.  Reading the style property directly from the object, only retrieves style values set directly on the object and does not retrieve default values.  It will not reflect what is set via CSS either.  You can implement a cross browser function for getting a style property including what is set via CSS like this from [this article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/dhtmlcascade4.shtml):

```
function getStyle(el, cssprop){
    if (el.currentStyle) //IE
        return el.currentStyle[cssprop]
    else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) //Firefox
        return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")[cssprop]
    else //try and get inline style
        return el.style[cssprop]
}
```

Then, you can implement your function like this:

```
    function show(id) {
        //alert("Its working");
        var myId = document.getElementById(id)
        if (getStyle(myId, "display") === "none") {
            myId.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            myId.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

Also, since your function is actually a toggle, not just a show, I'd suggest renaming it to `toggle()`.  You may also want to be aware that this will only work correctly with block elements.  If you try it on an inline element, it will hide it OK, but when it goes to show it, it will turn the inline element into a block element.

Comment: thank u so much ... i m just a beginner in javascript ... Ur help greatly appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(id)  // without the dot before parens
```

This code seems to work just fine with our without the double == suggested.  It wouldn't work until changing the (id) and removing the dot.

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function show(id){
            //alert("Its working");
            var myId=document.getElementById(id);
            if(myId.style.display=='none'){
                myId.style.display='block';
            }
            else{
                myId.style.display='none';
            }

        }
    </script>

<h1>Test</h1>

<input type="textbox" id="fname"></input>
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:show('select'); return false;">Click</button></br>
    <input type="radio" id="select" style="display:none;" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works fine for the first time because `='none'` returns true, it switches to `block`. After that it changes it to `block` over and over again. The `==` is necessary.

Comment: I also removed the closing tag on radio.

Comment: hey thank u so much ... it was the mistake that i had made .. Thank u very much..appreciated ur help :D

Answer (score 0):

```
   function show(id) {
        //alert("Its working");
        var myId = document.getElementById(id);
        if (myId.style.display == 'none') {
            myId.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            myId.style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
```

FTFY

Comment: @jfriend00 Brain barf. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

change this line:
    if(myId.style.display='none'){

to:

```
if(myId.style.display==='none'){
```